# Which apps/services needs to be whitelisted when using AFWall+ firewall?

Tags: firewall

I installed this root firewall app on my android but now some services are not working properly. For example, I liberated full access to Google play store on it and also Google play services but when I try to install an App in Play Store, it never starts the download. When I disable firewall, the downloads run normally.

Answer (score 3):

You likely blocked the downloads by *not whitelisting* `com.android.providers.downloads`

From [Question 58 of app FAQ](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/wiki/FAQ)

> What do I need to do to get Google Play Store to work?
>
> You need to whitelist the following: com.google.android.gms (Google Play Services for authorization) + **com.android.providers.downloads (For Downloads)** + com.android.vending (this is the Play Store)

(Emphasis Supplied)